# Can I ONLY use the calligraphy part of a font?

Tags: fonts

I'm using `\usepackage[utopia]{math-design}`and really enjoy the calligraphy font. However, I don't like the rest of the maths font. Therefore I want to hear whether it is possible to only use the calligraphy part of `utopia` and to use the standard LaTeX maths font for everything else

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE....

Comment: It almost answers my question. They say you must use ```\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}```, but I'm not sure what OMS and cmsy means, or rather what to replace it with, when trying to use my utopia font

Comment: @MadyYuvi -- Although this *is* a strong candidate for deletion as a duplicate, a brief specific answer here will help both the OP (who has indicated some confusion) and future searchers for information who may happen on this question before anything else.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I agree with you....